# ¿Cuántos días martes que caen en el día 2 existe en un rango de fecha en java?

Tags: java, date, localdate

Esto es una pregunta que terminó siendo cerrada porque el autor no ha ingresado ningún código.

**El cuerpo de la pregunta del autor fue exactamente la siguiente.**

> estoy teniendo problemas con un código en java, el cual me solicita que liste todos los martes, con número de fecha 2, los debe almacenar en una lista y luego mostrarlos, alguien me puede ayudar?

La razón por la que planteo la pregunta se debe a que muchas veces trabajar con fechas se nos hace complicado.

Comment: Te aconsejo que aclares en el cuerpo de la pregunta que la estas autorespondiendo, no vaya a ser q alguien se equivoque y la marque para cerrarla o le de un voto negativo

Comment: Hola @Japv, sí está resaltada ¿O debería realizar algo adicional?

Comment: Es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste en tu pregunta, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plantearé mi solución haciendo uso del api `java.time` que sólo está disponible en Java 8 y superiores, dejando de lado los antiguos api `java.util.Calendar` y `java.util.Date` que a opinión propia ya deberían dejarse.
Aquí planteo la solución a la pregunta, de todas formas esperando nuevas respuestas de la comunidad.

```
        //Fecha de hoy
        LocalDate fechaActual= LocalDate.now();
        //fecha de 31/12/2022
        LocalDate fechaFinal= LocalDate.of(2022, Month.DECEMBER, 31); 
        
        //creando un arreglo de tipo LocalDate
        ArrayList<LocalDate>listaFechas= new ArrayList<>();
        
        //comparamos si fecha actual es menor que fecha 31/12/2022
        while(fechaActual.compareTo(fechaFinal)<0){ 
            //si la fecha es un día martes y con el día 2
            if((fechaActual.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY))&&fechaActual.getDayOfMonth()==2){
                //agregamos la fecha que cumple la condición al ArrayList
                listaFechas.add(fechaActual);                              
            }  
            //agregamos un día a fecha actual para seguir con el bucle while
            fechaActual=fechaActual.plusDays(1);            
        } 
        
        //mostramos las fechas que contiene el ArrayList
        for(LocalDate fecha:listaFechas){
            System.out.println(fecha);
        }
```

Comment: Si bien el código funciona, es absurdo comparar TODOS los días... por qué recorres cada día del mes (sumando 1 a la fecha) y no te situas en el primer 2 que encuentras y recorres sumando 1 mes cada vez? Si vas saltando de día 2 en día 2, tu bucle se ejecutará solo 12 veces y no 365 por cada año :)

Comment: @Benito-B buena apreciación, para eso está el sitio para aprender de los errores, podrías editar la respuesta o dar otra respuesta con todos tus conocimientos que seguramente será mucho mejor que la mia

Comment: No veo necesario dar una respuesta que sería casi idéntica. Para eso están también los comentarios, cualquiera puede ver tu respuesta, y si mira los comentarios, verá cómo optimizarla :) Dejémosle algo de trabajo a quien busque respuestas de copiar y pegar! :)

Comment: @Benito-B gracias man, como programador novato se me pasa muchas detalles